# Google Sheet Script To Add Time To Specific Cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i need help with a script that will add a time value to a specific cell that contains a time value. For example, Cell A1 contains a time value like 09:30.
Then when the script runs, it will add 30 minutes to the time in A1 resulting it to be 10:00.

Appreciate the help.

Edit: Below is my current code

```
function modifyCell(cellName, increase) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellName)
  var AddTime = -30;
  if (increase) {
    AddTime = 30;
  }
  range.setValue(range.getValue() + AddTime);
}

function increaseLine2() {
  modifyCell("C5", true);
}

function decreaseLine2() {
  modifyCell("C5", false);
}
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: Currently, the script is adding the value 30 (Numerical) instead of the time value, 30 minutes to the specific cell. How do i change it such that it is adding in a time function?

Comment: how is the cell value currently being returned? does it look like this: `930` or like this: `9:30`?

Comment: My cell value is written as 9:30 and when the script runs, it becomes "Sat Dec 30 1899 09:24:17 GMT+0800 (HKT)30"

Comment: so when you print `range` to the console, that's what it shows you?

Comment: I assigned the script to a button and when i click on the button, it will run the script and modifies the specific cell which shows "Sat Dec 30 1899 09:24:17 GMT+0800 (HKT)30" after the script runs.

Comment: you probably formatted the cell to be a `date`. set the cell to be a text string

Comment: i formatted to cell to be a text string and it still gives me the same thing.

Comment: I went on Google sheets and formatted the cell to be `plain text` and it worked fine. Here is the code that increments by 30 mins: https://jsfiddle.net/thxLvLsq/

Comment: Thanks!! Your code worked great. But the problem is after the 24 hours. It does not go back to the next hour. Example: 24:00 will show 24:30 instead of 00:30.

Comment: then create a condition. if the first number before the `:` is 24, then change it to 00

Answer (score 0):

## A Digital Clock for dummies

Here's a digital clock that starts with correct time from the Date() function.  But when it's updated it just get 60 seconds added to it by taking the previous datetime value and adding 60*1000 milliseconds to it and formatting the date with the new value rather than using the available actual value.  So it only changes once every minute.  It also creates and manages a one minute timer for you.

```
function digitalClockMenu(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Clock Tools')
     .addItem('Start Clock', 'startDigitalClock')
     .addItem('Stop Clock', 'stopDigitalClock')
     .addToUi();
}

function startDigitalClock() {
  if(!isTrigger('addMinute')){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('addMinute').timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ClockSheet').getRange('A2').clearFormat().setValue('');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ClockSheet').getRange('A1').setValue('Starting');
}

function initialTime(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('ClockSheet');
  sh.getRange('A2').setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss"));
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue('Running');
}

function addMinute(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('ClockSheet');
  var v=sh.getRange('A2').getValue();
  if(v){
    var old=new Date(v).valueOf();
    var minute=60*1000;
    sh.getRange('A2').setValue(Utilities.formatString(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(old + minute), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss")));
  }else{
    initialTime();
  }
}

function stopDigitalClock(){
  deleteTrigger('addMinute');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ClockSheet').getRange('A1').setValue('Stopped');
}  


function isTrigger(funcName)
{
  var r=false;
  if(funcName)
  {
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    var allHandlers=[];
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++)
    {
      allHandlers.push(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction());
    }
    if(allHandlers.indexOf(funcName)>-1)
    {
      r=true;
    }
  }
  return r;
}

function deleteTrigger(funcName)
{
  var triggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for(var i=0;i<triggers.length;i++)
  {
    if(funcName==triggers[i].getHandlerFunction())
    {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

It does what you requested plus a little bit more.

Comment: +1 Heyy Thanks so much for this clock! But when i run it, there is an error "ReferenceError: "isTrigger" is not defined?. Can you help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function is there I just put comments around it because is messes up my stackoverflow projects when I have more that one function with the same name. I'll uncomment it for you.

Comment: Okay try it again.  I removed the comments.

Comment: Heyy! Thanks a lot!! it worked now but the problem now is that it is every time is addMinute func is triggered, it minus the time by 29 minutes instead of adding 29 minutes to the time. (Eg, 10:30 becomes 10:01 instead of 10:59). Secondly, the difference between the time is 29 min instead of 30min. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the help!

Comment: It works fine on my spreadsheet. It adds one minute on every 1 minute trigger.  I guess you still have debugging to do.

Comment: Thankss! It is okay, I have figured it out. Thanks for the help! really appreciate it!

Comment: Heyy sorry, but is there also a way to make it such that if the live time is more than the time in a specific cell, it will show a pop-up message? Example, if time in cell A1 is 10:00, and the live timing hits 10:01, it will show a pop-up message. Thanks for your help!